# Scala unit test in a maven project with IntelliJ

Tags: scala, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I have a scala project with maven as build tool, and I am using IntelliJ IDE.

What is the ideal folder structure for tests in this case? And what testing library should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the ideal folder structure for tests in this case?

In this [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html), checkout this section - **Explaining this Archetype**
It tells you the ideal folder structure for tests.

> what testing library should I use?

I think `scalatest` is a great testing tool for scala. You can add the following dependency in your pom.xml or checkout this [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest).

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scalatest/scalatest -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
    <artifactId>scalatest_2.13</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: MIne is a legacy project with no folders for test related files.